# Remove scrolling bar

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the scroll bar but still be able to scroll? I tried

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

but that removes the whole scrolling function..
Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
body{
   overflow: hidden !important;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 100vh;      // or height:100%;
}
```